# Get backslash in string with a string join

Tags: c#, string, join, backslash, single-quotes

I have the following code which must replace a ' with a \' in  a string (which I need to use in javascript later on). I do not seem to be able to get the backslash in the word.
Input: "Aujourd'hui"; Output wanted "Aujourd\'hui" (multiple single quotes in the input string may occur).

```
  char[] separators = new char[] { '\u0027' };

  string s = "Aujourd'hui";
  string[] temp = s.Split(separators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
  s = string.Join(@"\\'", temp);

  return (s);
```

What do I do wrong?

Comment: (Stack Overflow is not letting me type what I want to type here)  A backslash is either `@"\"` or `"\\"`.   **not** `@"\\"` (which is literally two backslashes)  So you want `"@\'"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove one of your backslashes to produce the literal text: `\'`

This code:

```
  s = string.Join(@"\\'", temp);
```

should be changed to:

```
  s = string.Join(@"\'", temp);
```

Comment: Don't feel bad.  You asked your question well, so no signs of stupidity at all.  :)  Some things are just tricky to see.